# db_delete rows older than 5 minutes

Tags: database

I have a table with a date column and I'd like to delete rows that are older than 5 minutes than "now".

I tried with db_delete conditions but it doesn't work.

I tried this query:

```
$deleteOldRows = db_delete('reserves') 
    ->condition('entityId', -1) 
    ->condition('dataReg + 5 MINUTES', 'NOW()') 
    ->execute();
```

Comment: Could you post the code that you have tried here so we can review it?

Comment: I tried this query:
$deleteOldRows = db_delete('reserves')
     ->condition('entityId', -1)
     ->condition('dataReg + 5 MINUTES', 'NOW()')
     ->execute();

Comment: Could you edit the question and include that?

Comment: Done it, sorry!

Comment: No problem, now we have a proper question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the condition syntax; it looks like below and performs a binary comparison:

```
$query->condition($field, $value = NULL, $operator = '=')
```

There are several issues, there is no field `dataReg + 5 MINUTES` and it likely won't have the literal value `NOW()` either. Besides, since you omitted the operator, the query would (if it had worked) only select items that are exactly 5 minutes old.

You are looking for a way to execute SQL in the query instead, which is provided by the `where` clause:

```
$query->where($snippet, $args = array())
```

In your case, it would probably look like this:

```
$deleteOldRows = db_delete('reserves') 
  ->condition('entityId', -1) 
  ->where('`dataReg` + 5 MINUTES < :time', array(':time' => 'NOW()')) 
  ->execute();
```

You can find some good information on conditional clauses here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/conditional-clauses

**UPDATE**

It appears I was wrong and this can be done with conditions after all, you should just reverse the logic. Rather than adding 5 minutes to the date, subtract 5 minutes from now.

```
$query->condition('dataReg', $adjusted_date, '<=')
```

Where `$adjusted_date` for timestamps would be `time() - (5*60)`. And for DATE types something like `date('Y-m-t H:i:s', time() - (5*60))`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried the code you posted but it returns a syntax error, I looked for the documentation but I can't understand how to correctly write the condition 'dataReg + 5 MINUTES'

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Comment: Damn, I didn't think to reverse the logic, you're right! Thank you!!!